# Does Furry's Theorem for QED hold in lower dimensions as well?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, symmetry, charge-conjugation

In $1+3$ dimensional QED, it is well-known that an amplitude for a process described by a Feynman diagram with odd number of vertices is zero.

This is [Furry's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furry%27s_theorem).

I wonder if this theorem holds true in lower spatial dimensions.

For example, in $1+2$ dimensional QED, does Furry's Theorem holds by exactly the same argument as in the $1+3$ dimensional case?

I strongly suspect so, but would like to check for sure. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: As long as you have parity symmetry, it'll hold in any dimension.

Comment: Exactly the same argument. A charge conjugation operator commutes with  the charge and the photon in any dimension, so the WP argument goes through. The U(1) of EM gauge invariance cares not about spacetime dimensionality.